# SignInManager SignOutAsync not working after share cookies across subdomains

Tags: asp.net-core

For SSO in multi subdomain, Based on [Share cookies across subdomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-cookies-across-subdomains) i set `options.Cookie.Name='.example.com'`:

```
         services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie1";
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });
```

After setting domain for cookie, `_signInManager.SignOutAsync()` not logout user and authentication cookie not removed.
I try to remove cookie manually but doesn't work:

```
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Cookie1", "", new CookieOptions()
        {
            Domain= ".example.com",
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        });
```

Comment: Is the AuthenticationScheme of your project  a cookie-based authentication provider without ASP.NET Core Identity ?

Comment: No, it's based on Core Identity.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Maddie add this code to first line of ConfigureService at startup.cs and remove cookie manually in signout:  
 ` services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });`